# Drawing buttons dynamically from top

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have trouble with dynamic drawing buttons in WPF. I want to draw this buttons from top, but it's drawing from middle, and I can't figure out why. There is a code drawing these buttons.

```
public partial class UserView : UserControl {
    public UserView(IEnumerable<User> usersFromDb) {
        var spacer = 0;
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (var user in usersFromDb) {
            var canvas = new Canvas {
                Width = 1080,
                Height = 70
            };

            var canavasThickness = canvas.Margin;
            canavasThickness.Top = spacer;
            canvas.Margin = canavasThickness;
            UserGrid.Children.Add(canvas);

            var button = new Button {
                Width = 1080,
                Height = 70,
                FontSize = 20,
                Content = $"{user.Name} {user.Surname}",
                Background = Brushes.Azure,
                Foreground = Brushes.Black
            };

            canvas.Children.Add(button);

            spacer += 150;
        }
    }
}
```

[Picture from app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rls4B.png)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Looks like your UserControl is vertically centered in the Window. Besides that, doing layout by Margins is generally a bad idea. Instead of putting the Buttons in a Canvas in a Grid, put them in a StackPanel, which is designed for vertical or horizontal layout. You should also consider using an ItemsControl instead of a UserControl. ItemsControl is the base control for displaying collections of items. If you also need the ability of selecting items, use a ListBox or ListView. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ok, thank you for tips, I'll do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution

```
foreach (var user in usersFromDb)
            {
                var canvas = new Canvas
                {
                    Width = 1080,
                    Height = 70
                };

                var canavasThickness = canvas.Margin;
                canavasThickness.Top = spacer;
                canvas.Margin = canavasThickness;
                canvas.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top; // <------ THIS IS THE SOLUTION <-------- //
                UserGrid.Children.Add(canvas);

                var button = new Button
                {
                    Width = 1080,
                    Height = 70,
                    FontSize = 20,
                    Content = $"{user.Name} {user.Surname}",
                    Background = Brushes.Azure,
                    Foreground = Brushes.Black
                };

                canvas.Children.Add(button);

                spacer += 150;
            }
```

Please consider dependency properties - to bind your Data at least...

```
public partial class UserView : UserControl
    {



        public ObservableCollection<User> UserViewCollection
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<User>)GetValue(UserViewCollectionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UserViewCollectionProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UserViewCollection.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UserViewCollectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UserViewCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<User>), typeof(UserView), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCollectionChanged));



        private static void OnCollectionChanged(DependencyObject d,  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            UserView self = d as UserView;

            if(self != null)
            {
                self.UpdateButtonsInCodeBehind(args.NewValue as ObservableCollection<User>);
            }
        }



        public UserView()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void UpdateButtonsInCodeBehind(ObservableCollection<User> collection)
        {
            if(collection != null)
            {
                UserGrid.Children.Clear();
                var spacer = 0;
                foreach (var user in collection)
                {
                    var canvas = new Canvas
                    {
                        Width = 1080,
                        Height = 70
                    };

                    var canavasThickness = canvas.Margin;
                    canavasThickness.Top = spacer;
                    canvas.Margin = canavasThickness;
                    canvas.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top; // <------ THIS IS THE SOLUTION <-------- //
                    UserGrid.Children.Add(canvas);

                    var button = new Button
                    {
                        Width = 1080,
                        Height = 70,
                        FontSize = 20,
                        Content = $"{user.Name} {user.Surname}",
                        Background = Brushes.Azure,
                        Foreground = Brushes.Black
                    };

                    canvas.Children.Add(button);

                    spacer += 150;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can bind the collection - like with a `ItemsControl`. If you dont know what that means - pls check out MVVM with WPF. Tutorial Link [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_wpf_data_bindings.htm)

The Simple solution works too but its ugly! Why not overriding a ListViewTemplate...

Comment: Thank you for tutorial link! I'm not familiar with WPF, data binding and MVVM so you see effects.